# Set color to unselected tab indicator in tab layout

Tags: android

I am using tablayout provided by google and everything is working fine except the color of the unselected tab indicator. I am unable to set the unselected tab indicator color.

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
         android:id="@+id/tabs"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         app:tabMode="fixed"
         style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"

         />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this changing the color as you wish:

Create this file in drawable folder

**tab_indicator_color.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#65acee" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and after set your .xml file in app:tabBackground like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_color" />
```

Comment: heyy i was wondering how to set the tabs to the left... i am talking about the tabs like in tinder...they are aligned left.

Comment: check out this library https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout .There is an example(the last one in the app and the last one in the site) very similar, although the tab indicator is above instead of below

Comment: @CarlosHernándezGil So how to set the background if hat set the indicator after this.

Comment: not worked, created border on whole tab, i required only bottom line

Comment: Just decrease left and right margin as android:left="-500dp" android:right="-500dp". If values smaller than tab's width, borders will display like in your situation. @ArbazRizvi

Comment: @AtaerCaner's answer should be part of the accepted solution. Otherwise, you probably won't be able to get the left and right borders out

Answer (score 21):

```
**1.app:**

    tabBackground="@drawable/tablayout_selector"

**2.tablayout_selector.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/shl_common_default_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <inset android:insetBottom="1.5dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</layer-list>


or

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/shl_common_default_color" />
            <size android:height="1.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Works for AndroidX TabLayout :+1:

Comment: perfect, perfect!

Answer (score 15):

**ic_tab_indicator_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/steel_blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**ic_tab_indicator_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="3dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/congress_blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**selector_tab_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_indicator_default" />
</selector>
```

**TabLayout**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector_tab_indicator">
```

Comment: This makes the smooth sliding animation gone

Answer (score 7):

For people using the new com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout if you apply the solution given as the correct answer in this post would get corners on all four sides of the tab

To fix that use the following "hack"

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
            <item  android:top="-10dp" android:left="-1000dp" android:right="-1000dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <stroke android:color="#4cffffff" android:width="1dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: only solution here working on api 16, 17, 18, 22, 23 and 29

Comment: Works for material.tabs.TabLayout. Removed corners that showed up! +1

Answer (score 2):

If your TabLayout **don't need title**, but need indicator for unselected color.
You can do like

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_normal"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="10dp" />
```

[image]

The workaround here is

- Using both `tabBackground` and `tabIndicator`
- Indicator height equals to TabLayout height

**tab_normal.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#aaaaaa" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**tab_indicator.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

- If you need a padding between indicator, you can use `layer-list` drawable with some padding (instead of using `shape`)
- If you just only need a color for tab indicator, no need to define shape drawable, can use

  - `app:tabBackground="@color/gray"`
  - `app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"`